# Best solution for generating three phase for robot controller

Tags: three-phase

I have a Staubli CS9 controller. This controller requires three-phase 400-480v or three-phase 200-230v. I do not know the controller's max amp draw, horsepower equivalent or even leg to leg/ leg to neutral requirements. This information is not in the robots manual nor is it on any equipment plate. Unfortunately, I only have access to single-phase 240vac. I am completely blind when it comes to does and don'ts of ac. Things that I have looked into for supplying converting the single phase are: solid state converters, VFD converter and Rotary Phase Converter.

Obviously, I am most concerned with frying the controller because of an unsafe/unclean power supply. I am leaning towards the Rotary Phase Converter as being the correct solution. Can you please provide information on what would be an adequate?

Comment: My first thought: Devices often require 3-phase because a single-phase circuit may not have enough power.

Comment: Go hire yourself a diesel generator.